# In Julia, why does a string sometimes present as an iterator of characters but not a collection?

Tags: string, collections, iterator, julia

In Julia, these examples of a string being treated as an iterator (delivering characters) work:

```
number = "1234"
notnumber = "123z"
isgood = all(isdigit, number) # true
isobad = all(isdigit, notnumber) # false
isgood = mapreduce(isdigit, &, number) # also true
isbad = mapreduce(isdigit, &, notnumber) # also false
myhex = mapreduce(codepoint, &, number) # 0x00000030
avector = map(codecode, collect(number))
```

but this does not work, despite isdigit() and codepoint() having a very similar signatures:

```
avector = map(codepoint, number) # causes error
```

Why is it sometimes necessary to use collect() on the string? If the answer is because all() and mapreduce() take iter and map() takes collection, please explain the distinction?

Is using collect() with map() wrong, because it leads to longer execution times or greater memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `map` and `filter` have a special implementation for `AbstractString`. They iterate a string and **return a string**. Therefore, in `map` it is required that the function you pass returns `AbstractChar`. Here is an example:

```
julia> x = "a12b3"
"a12b3"

julia> map(uppercase, x)
"A12B3"
```

and a similar example with `filter`:

```
julia> filter(isdigit, x)
"123"
```

Now if you do not want not to have a string as a result of `map` but rather a vector then use `collect` (which is expensive as you note), or use a comprehension:

```
julia> [codepoint(c) for c in x]
5-element Vector{UInt32}:
 0x00000061
 0x00000031
 0x00000032
 0x00000062
 0x00000033
```